# Why does my inventory system return unexpected token o in JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I'm making an RPG-ish Discord bot that needs an inventory system. I decided to store the inventory data in a separate JSON array, with every player's user ID being their inventory data. That data is stored like so:

```
[["item-id", <integer for amount of said item owned>], ["item-id"] ...]
```

Every change to the inventory is saved using `fs.writeFileSync()`. All item data is stored in `items.json`. What I do, is when the system searches for the item name, it looks at the ID and returns the name of the item associated with the ID.

However, when I run the code, it returns `Unexpected token o in JSON`, while I never did `JSON.parse()` at wrong moments. Please take a look at my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    //------------------------------------------------
    const id = message.author.id;
    //------------------------------------------------
    var userData = require('./userdata.json');
    var inventory = require('./inventory.json');
    var items = require('./items.json');

    if (userData[id] === undefined) {
        userData[id] = {
            username: message.author.username,
            level: 1,
            xp: 0,
            eventJoins: 0,
            crystals: 0
        };
        inventory[id] = [
            ['example', 1]
        ];
        fs.writeFileSync('userdata.json', userData[id], (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        fs.writeFileSync('inventory.json', inventory[id], (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    }
    
        if (command === 'inventory' || command === 'inv') {
        var inventoryText = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < inventory[id].length; i++) {
            let itemFinder = items.find(obj => obj.id === inventory[id][i][0]);
            inventoryText = inventoryText.concat(`${inventory[id][i][1]}x ${itemFinder.name}`);
            console.log(itemFinder.name);
        }
        console.log(inventoryText);
    }
```

My JSON files:

items.json

```
[
    {
        "name": "Example item",
        "id": "example",
        "buyprice": 50,
        "sellprice": 25
    }
]
```

userdata.json

```
[
    {
        "placeholder": "placeholder"
    }
]
```

This placeholder is to prevent the file from clearing itself due to not containing any real data.

inventory.json

```
[
    "placeholder"
]
```

This placeholder is to prevent the file from clearing itself due to not containing any real data.

I reconstructed the core premise of the code in playcode.io, and somehow it worked, so I deducted it must be a problem in the exporting of data. Take a look:

```
var items = [
  {
    name: "item1",
    id: "id1"
  },
  {
    name: "item2",
    id: "id2"
  },
  {
    name: "item3",
    id: "id3"
  }
]

var arr = [[["id1", 1], ["id2", 3], ["id3", 10]], [["id2", 1], ["id1", 3], ["id3", 10]]];

var userId = 0;

var output = "";
for(var i = 0; i < arr[userId].length; i++) {
  let finder = items.find(obj => obj.id === arr[userId][i][0]);
  output = output.concat(`\n${arr[userId][i][1]}x ${finder.name}`);
}
console.log(output);

/*
Output: 
>  1x item1
   3x item2
   10x item3
*/
```

What I've reconstructed is the desired result.

---

**Update on this question**

I've done a bit more research, I optimized this string of code:

```
    var userData = require('./userdata.json');
    var inventory = require('./inventory.json');
    var items = require('./items.json');

    if (!userData.find(obj => obj.userId === id)) {
        userData.push = {
            userId: id,
            level: 1,
            xp: 0,
            eventJoins: 0,
            crystals: 0
        };
        inventory.push = {
            userId: id,
            items: [
                ['example-id', 1]
            ]
        }
        JSON.stringify(userData[id]);
        JSON.stringify(inventory[id]);

        console.log(userData, inventory);

        fs.writeFileSync('userdata.json', userData, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        fs.writeFileSync('inventory.json', inventory, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    }
```

The console.log outputs:

```
[
    {
        placeholder: 'placeholder'
    },
    push: {
        <all the userdata pushed into the array>
    }
]
```

Then it stores the data in the userdata file like this:

```
[Object object]
```

What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: You don't stringify the data before writing it. Also you write out a different structure than you read in, so over time other unexpected things will likely happen.

Comment: @ShadeOfLight You should use MongoDB to store your data,in that case unexpected things will not happen.

Comment: Oh! Bad mistake, I will try using stringify